# Problems with ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I have a variable of type `List<Foo>` declared on the top of my C# class in my ASP.NET project. In the load method I instanciate this class, but when I try to use this object (already instanciated in load method) in another method it is null, giving me the error ArgumentNullException.
Here's how I'm doing it:

```
public partial class Teste : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<Foo> myList;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            myList = new List<Foo>();
    }

    protected void btnTeste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myList.Add(new Foo { Id = 0, Name = "Nobody" }); //NullReferenceException - myList is null here!
    }
}
```

It may be simple, but I'm new to web forms so I don't know what's happening here. I know that in windows forms it works just fine.
The only way I got it to work was declaring as static:

```
static List<Foo> myList;
```

But I don't think it's the right way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having it as `static` won't help the Null Reference Exception.

You need to understand your check `if (!IsPostBack)`  in your `Page_Load` event and remember that **Web is stateless**.

So On your first page load, your List is instantiate. What happens next is when you click your button. Now it is a Post Back and that will cause `!IsPostBack` check to return `false`. Here one would think that the `List` has been instantiated previously and doesn't require instantiation again. **But the web is stateless, so on a `Page_Load` the `List` has lost the contents and it is being set to `null` again.**

You need to maintain your state. There are various ways to do it, `ViewState`, `Session` and cookies come to mind. Read about them and use accordingly.

In your case you can do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        myList = new List<Foo>();
        Session["myList"] = myList;
    }
    else
    {
        myList = Session["myList"] as List<Foo>;
    }
}
```

and in Button Click

```
protected void btnTeste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myList.Add(new Foo { Id = 0, Name = "Nobody" });
    Session["myList"] = myList; //save it back in session
}
```

This will restore the original list on post back. But remember **Sessions are expensive** as they are maintained per user on the server.

You can also use `ViewState` but that will require a Serializable object.

To make a class `Serializable` see: [Basic Serialization - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[Serializable]
class Foo
{
  public int ID { get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and then you can use `ViewState` instead of `Session` in the above code . The advantage of `ViewState` is that it will be maintained page wise on client side and there will be no burden on server like in case of `Session`. So your code with `ViewState` would be like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        myList = new List<Foo>();
        ViewState["myList"] = myList;
    }
    else
    {
        myList = ViewState["myList"] as List<Foo>;
    }
}
```

and for Button click:

```
protected void btnTeste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myList.Add(new Foo { Id = 0, Name = "Nobody" });
    ViewState["myList"] = myList; //save it back in session
}
```

You may see: [ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Habib for your explanation, I'll do it with ViewState then. I appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize all variables at every postback because all variables (and controls) are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle, so after it was rendered and sent to the client.

So replace

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    myList = new List<Foo>();
```

with

```
myList = new List<Foo>();
```

You should also not use `static` fields in ASP.NET since they are shared acrosss all requests. That means every user has the same list.

If you want to retain the list across postback you could use the `Session`. But i advise against this. Why do you need to store it in server memory at all? If you need to use it as `DataSource` for a web-databound control like `Repeater` or `GridView` you don't need to store it. Just let the `ViewState` restore the state of the controls. That is done automatically by default.

Comment: Although this will solve the issue with NRE, but it will end up with a new `List` on every post back, which I think, is not required.

Comment: @Habib: i don't know if it's required but i also doubt that. I have edited my answer already.

Answer (score 0):

On each `PostbBack`, your variable will be at null. You have to provide a way to regenerate it. If you want to do it the simple way, use the `ViewState`.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     myList = new List<Foo>();
     ViewState["myList"] = myList;
}
else
{
     myList = (List<Foo>)ViewState["myList"];
}

protected void btnTeste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myList.Add(new Foo { Id = 0, Name = "Nobody" }); //NullReferenceException - myList is null here!
    ViewState["myList"] = myList;
}
```

Comment: `ViewState` requires serializable data.

Comment: True, but still better than putting in session. At least the viewstate is only for the current page. Not the best option since it will make it heavier for the client to download. However, it was more to show the concept.

Comment: Absolutely right. Just thought you should mention it in your answer.

Comment: I'll be more careful on my next answers. Thanks for the output.

Answer (score 0):

You only instantiate when `!IsPostBack`. The button click event is a postback. You need to rework your logic based on what you are trying to accomplish. What is stored in the `List<Foo>`? Consider placing the object in Session Cache if you intend to use repeatedly or on multiple pages.